# Not seeeing "Reply" link to app in Facebook Messenger Platform integration

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-messenger

I was implementing optimized integration for Facebook Messenger Platform for my iOS app using the SDK and am facing a few issues. When I share content from my app to Facebook Messenger, I always see the "Install" link alongside my app link, even though the app is installed. Also, I never see the "Reply" button on the content shared from my app, just Install.

Both the sender and receiver have Admin access to the corresponding Facebook app. (The FB integration features are currently in dev, even though the app is live).

Followed all the sequence of steps mentioned in the documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios

FBSDKMessengerURLHandler callbacks are implemented for FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerReplyContext and FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerOpenFromComposerContext as well.

Not sure how to proceed to test the features. Anybody else faced the same problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This typically means that you haven't added the (right) schemes to your plist. Have you added fb{app_id} as a custom scheme, and verified that it works (go into safari and type it in to see if it opens your app)?

Comment: What you suggested seems precisely the issue and now I see the reply links on the content shared in Messenger. Many many thanks!

Comment: Please consider writing this up as an answer so it is clearer to others what the solution is. Next, kinshukkar can accept the answer.

Comment: Another cause of this could be that you're not signed in as a user with the correct role. Note that Test users do NOT seem to get the reply link before the app is reviewed / Apple ID is added- I had to sign in as a user with the admin role to see the Reply link during testing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Find *any* valid iOS App Store ID and fill it in on the developers.facebook.com page (near where you enter the Bundle ID info).

Relaunching Messenger made the Reply button start to show up on new messages.

The developer community at Facebook is pretty awful.